# Laravel 8 {{$slot}} is showing wire:id="" wire:initial-data=".... error

Tags: laravel-8

I very new to Laravel, I am getting the following error

< wire:id="iET0Mm7xmFXag9CCrYZF" wire:initial-data="{"fingerprint":{"id":"iET0Mm7xmFXag9CCrYZF","name":"home-component","locale":"en","path":"/","method":"GET"},"effects":{"listeners":[]},"serverMemo":{"children":[],"errors":[],"htmlHash":"0839940e","data":[],"dataMeta":[],"checksum":"1b400c4dccab96b4573b31763cbfe17d874dd572025968495c032f59d9273984"}}"

Following is my app>http>Livewire>HomeComponent.php file:
namespace App\Http\Livewire;

```
use Livewire\Component;

class HomeComponent extends Component
{
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.home-component')->layout('layouts.base');
    }
}
```

and my web.php is:

```
 Route::get('/',HomeComponent::class);
```

in view > layouts > base.blade.php I have added `{{ $slot }}` .

Can anyone please help me to fix the error?

Answer (score 2):

Just simple enclose the complete livewire component within single   tag
like

```
 <div>

//yourcodein livewire component.php

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Incase anybody else has the same issue it turned out to be the note at the start of the one of the child component blade views needed deleting. So best to check all of them.

So...

```
<!-- Content -->
<div class="mt-2">
```

Becomes

```
<div class="mt-2">
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead use layout

```
return view('livewire.home-component')->layout('layouts.base');
```

use extends

```
return view('livewire.home-component')->extends('layouts.base');
```

UPDATE
Then use the yield directive

```
<main class="py-4">
   @yield('content')
</main>
```

and in the component

```
return view('livewire.home-component')
         ->extends('layouts.base')
         ->section('content');
```

Comment: Thanks For your comment.. But now I am getting this error:

ErrorException
Undefined variable: slot (View: D:\Laravel\laravelecommerce\resources\views\layouts\base.blade.php)